# Error - No suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, constructor, syntax-error

I have this code in one of the tabs of an android application :-

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        String str[]={"Arun","Mathev","Vishnu","Vishal","Arjun",
                "Arul","Balaji","Babu","Boopathy","Godwin","Nagaraj"};

        AutoCompleteTextView t1 = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,str);

        t1.setThreshold(1);
        t1.setAdapter(adp);
        return rootView;
```

and the following line is underlined in red hence causing an error

> (this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,str)

i tried to edit it but the problem still remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the default contructor of `ArrayAdapter` that you using and you should pass the `Context` as first parameter

> ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, List objects)

So change

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,str);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,str);
```

Comment: getActivity() in not the best solution, as it will produce an exception if the Fragment is not attached :-(

Comment: @Kelevandos you are right, but in some case we still can use `getActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    container.getContext(),                
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
    str);
```

`Fragment` itself is not a `Context` and you need to pass context as the first parameter :-)

As a side note, you may also use `getActivity()` instead of `container.getContext()`, but this may produce an exception if the `Fragment` is not attached (may happen if you use the `Fragments` in an adapter for example)